# Passing Disabled Form Input Value On Post Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form which has an email field. I am adding the value of the form field with `interpolation`. But I do not want the user to be able to change the email address in the form field. So I add the `disabled` flag to the `input field`. When I add `disabled` the form does not pass the email to the `http post`.

How can I disable this input field but still show the email address init to the user so that it will still post when the form is submitted with the rest of the form data?

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" 
[(ngModel)]="personal.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" required
 value="{{auth.userProfile.email}}" placeholder="{{auth.userProfile.email}}" disabled>`

Maybe I am confused about `two way data binding` but can I not just add the value to it with something like this,

```
[(ngModel)]="personal.email"
=
{{auth.userProfile.email}}
```

Then still keep the form input field disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" 
[(ngModel)]="personal.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" required
 value="{{auth.userProfile.email}}" placeholder="{{auth.userProfile.email}}" readonly>`
do not use disable. 
if  you wanna pass value then use readonly (readonly="readonly").
it will let you post the value

Comment: When I leave required on it wont let me submit the form. When I remove required the form submits but it wont pass the value still.. But when I leave readonly or disabled off of it the form passes the value just fine.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the value does not exist till the form gets submitted but it appears in the form field when i use it as placeholder.